# Design for ApiController, Viewmodel and DTO

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm, architecture

I'm planning a "universal" client-server-architecture. The current structure looks like this:

### Server

- Asp.Net WebApp (hosted local or in azure)
- EntityFrameworkCore Datalayer
- WebApi with Controllers for each EF-Model, sending flat DTOs

### Client

- ApiClient, receiving DTOs
- Viewmodels for each View (MVVM), working with several different DTOs. Relationship between Entitys need to be manually connected by Entity-IDs.

As many tutorials show, that's the way to go. But I'm unsure with some things.

- When calling my Api from my ViewModel, i need multiple calls (one for each entity i need). Wouldn't it be faster to just create a ApiController for my ViewModel that gives me everything i need in one call? That's against common patterns i guess, but what speaks against it? The whole client-side logic is executed on the server and the client stays clean and dumb.
- The comfortable Linq-syntax of entity-framework is not useable on the client side. Is there a comparable thing wrapping all the "receive-dto-and-create-relations" stuff?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can abstract those ideas about architecture that your read on the internet, a good architecture is actually the one which can solve your problems in a more effective way. 
My advice is to not stick to those architectures, open your mind, think outside the box. You could create an API Controller, or you could just create a Proxy class(http://www.dofactory.com/net/proxy-design-pattern), to abstract those api calls.

Another way, you could just join the data on the api side. It is not obligatory to return data related to a unique entity using the api. You could just create another class and model the data the way you need.

> The comfortable Linq-syntax of entity-framework is not useable on the
>   client side. Is there a comparable thing wrapping all the
>   "receive-dto-and-create-relations" stuff?

Well, you can always use lambda expressions to query your data, when you are using a .net collection, it is very much like entity-framework linq, the only difference is that you are not manipulating your data direct from the database, only in memory data.

Answer (score 1):

> When calling my Api from my ViewModel, i need multiple calls (one for each entity i need). Wouldn't it be faster to just create a ApiController for my ViewModel that gives me everything i need in one call? That's against common patterns i guess, but what speaks against it? The whole client-side logic is executed on the server and the client stays clean and dumb.

That is NOT against common patterns. Create your API methods according to your use cases and return all data you need. Looks like you are trying to create a RESTful API but REST API doesn't have to be just plain CRUD API. Anything can be a resource.

> The comfortable Linq-syntax of entity-framework is not useable on the client side. Is there a comparable thing wrapping all the "receive-dto-and-create-relations" stuff

DTO is not necessary flat. It might have other objects inside of it. If you use JSON serializer to pass data to the client your DTO should be deserialized as a Javascript object with all relations preserved. Also check [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org) library. It has many helpful functions to work with Javascript objects in a LINQ like way.

Comment: Okay, I will customize my CRUD Apis to something matching my use cases. I'm with C# on the client side, but when i deserialize complex DTOs i should still be able to wirk LINQ-like. ;)

Comment: what do you mean you are with C# on the client side? If you mean browser by the client it's not possible unless you do silverlight or something like that. You must be confusing client side with view rendering

Comment: WPF/Winforms/Xamarin

Comment: Just use JSON serialize to pass the data, on the client side you can deserialize your DTOs and have the same objects structure